# Stale nodes left with animation classes in angularjs app

Tags: angularjs

I have a list repeated in DOM with `ng-repeat`. The rows have `transition` property defined on them in CSS. At times after some manipulation to the repeated list, stale nodes remain in the DOM which look like following:

[image: Stale nodes with animation classes]

These have animation classes (ng-animate, ng-leave etc) on them so it looks like animation is in progress on them. And when I hover on those nodes, they go away immediately.

Anyone facing such issue?

**Edit**

This was a bug in angular which has been solved in 1.2.15.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6748

Solved now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in angular-animate module which has been solved in 1.2.15.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6748

For the curious, this was the fix: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/ff5cf736e5b8073c8121295743873ccd04cc7d6b